# Unmatching views count between question counter and badge earned

Tags: bug

**I just wanted to report the following:**

**1.** I received this notification:

[image]

**2.** However, when I went to check it, I got

[image]

Comment: When you click on the actual post, you'll see this in the "header" area: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jfMU.png) I assume this speaks to unique vs total views.